# How can we take the screenshot of iphone/ipad device using HID keyboard key press?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.5

i want to create app which helps us to take screen shot using HID keyboard key press but i did 't know how can i detect the HID keyboard key press.please help me and thanks in advance

Comment: What is HID Keyboard Key Press?

Comment: it is Wireless apple keyboard

Comment: can anybody tell me is there any way to take screen shot of the your iPhone with the keyboard key press

Comment: If you are asking for taking screenshot in the ios simulator. press CommandKey and S to take screenshot.

Comment: @iPrabu no you did't understand me i want to generate app the help to create screen shot of the iphone screen from every screen of the iphone we can take screen shot by the click of any HID keyboard keys(apple wireless keyboard keys) in the iPhone for example when we use cydia to take any language in my iphone then it provide other language keyboard everywhere in the iphone such as i want to set that where we go i want one key of the keyboard that help to take screen shot

Comment: use Keyboard notification

Answer (score 0):

i dont know about that special keyboard but using of this code you can take a scree shot from your application. You can put this code in button action and check it's working but about your keyboard i have no idea.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.window.bounds.size);
[self.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[data writeToFile:@"foo.png" atomically:YES];
```

UPDATE April 2011: for retina display, change the first line into this:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.window.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
else
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.window.bounds.size);
```

Comment: amit soni can you chat with me so that i will provide you more info about this question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Keyboard notification`

```
#pragma mark - Keyboard notification
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)keyboardWillBeShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{

}
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{

}
```

Comment: thanx for rply but i does not need this type of code that you provided i want to access the Wireless keyboard attached to iphone and help to print the screen of the iphone please check this link:http://www.engadget.com/2009/12/24/want-to-connect-your-iphone-and-bluetooth-keyboard-theres-a-j/